# CreateDispatch failed when called from dll .vs. exe

Tags: ole, ocx

I have an OCX that has been updated, and a **.exe** and a .dll that both use it.  My problem is that while the **.exe** can connect and use the OCX just fine, the .dll is having problems.  Specifically, the `CreateDispatch(clsid, &e)` call fails with an 80040154 exception (class not registered).  Both the .exe and the .dll are on the same machine, and the connection code is practically identical.  I've looked in the archives for CreateDispatch problems, but none of the answers seem to apply. The only other thing to note is that the .dll is a 32-bit ODBC Driver setup module, called from the **ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)** utility.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us more information about the programming environment. What about a simple VBScript testcode using CreateObject, does this work (use it from a 32bit Windows\Syswow64 folder...)

Comment: Did you find a solution?